# Which is better for recurring tasks at a specific interval of time Queue or cron?

Tags: architecture, cron, jvm, queue, microservices

In my system I need to collect system information like garbage collector memory snapshots, system statistics and various micro services application data at a different intervals for the monitoring and reporting purposes.

So,for this I have two solutions whether I can go with the tradational approach of using multiple cron jobs at defined intervals.

or 
using the queue delay mechanism for performing jobs. I understand if I use queues then there might be more delay because of more messages in queues. but concurrent workers will resolve this problem.

So, Which should be better queue or cron? If I have to develop scalable, maintainable system.

Comment: Just a suggestion, why don't you consider using APM solutions available ready-made like newrelic or Metric-beat integration of ELK stack ?

Comment: When there are tons of great solutions/products for the problem/use case is available online, why do you have to re-invent the wheel ?

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you can rather go for dedicated solution for monitoring like prometheus via micrometer(for spring boot) or drop-wizard metrics and can make use of the tools that are tailor made for monitoring and reporting purposes.
If you have already considered these, then between cron and queue, I will prefer cron mostly because queue should be used as a channel for passing events and not as trigger in all by itself.

Comment: Thanks Anunay, for response yes I am using grafana and InfluxDB for monitoring purpose. If I use cron main issue is to manage those tasks in a effective way.

Comment: Why you need cron exactly? to push the metrics? If so dropwizard and micrometer will take care of it for you, or is it for something else?